# After specifying a DataTextField and DataValueField, why doesn't my DropDownList show the elements of my List?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a `DropDownList`, but I have some troubles with the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. The drop-down doesn't show the elements of the list.

```
private void llenarProfesionales()
{
    List<Profesional> profesionales = daoProfesionales.getAll();
    DropDownProfesioanles.DataSource = profesionales;
    DropDownProfesioanles.DataTextField = "nombre";
    DropDownProfesioanles.DataValueField = "id";
    DropDownProfesioanles.DataBind();
}
```

Here is my class `profesional` that extends `usuario`:

```
public class Profesional: Usuario
{
    long idProfesional;
    List<Servicio> listaServicios;
    Profesion profesion;
    Usuario usuar;

    Decimal comision;

    public Decimal Comision
    {
        get { return comision; }
        set { comision = value; }
    }


    public Profesional()
    { 
    }

    public long IdProfesional
    {
        get { return idProfesional; }
        set { idProfesional = value; }
    }

    public List<Servicio> ListaServicios
    {
        get { return listaServicios; }
        set { listaServicios = value; }
    }

    public Profesion Profesion
    {
        get { return profesion; }
        set { profesion = value; }
    }

    public Usuario Usuar
    {
        get { return usuar; }
        set { usuar = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is the class `usuario`:

```
public class Usuario
{
    private long id;

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String telefono;
    private String celular;
    private Boolean activo;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(string nombre, string apellido, string telefono , string celular, string user, string password ,long id, bool activo) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Apellido = apellido;
        this.Telefono = telefono;
        this.Celular = celular;
        this.User = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.activo = activo;
    }

    public long Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public String Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }

    public String Apellido
    {
        get { return apellido; }
        set { apellido = value; }
    }

    public String Telefono
    {
        get { return telefono; }
        set { telefono = value; }
    }
    public String Celular
    {
        get { return celular; }
        set { celular = value; }
    }

    public String Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }
    public Boolean Activo
    {
        get { return activo; }
        set { activo = value; }
    }
    public String User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the public properties, not the private fields:

```
DropDownProfesioanles.DataTextField = "Nombre";
DropDownProfesioanles.DataValueField = "Id";
```

Also, there's no reason to define your class like this, where you define a public `Usuario` property, but also extend the `Usuario` class (so you'll have access to all of its properties, but they won't have any values since you're using the separate "Usuar" variable).

```
public class Profesional : Usuario
{
    ...
    Usuario usuar;

    ...
    public Usuario Usuar
    {
        get { return usuar; }
        set { usuar = value; }
    }
}
```

If you're going to use the public property, then don't extend the other class:

```
public class Profesional
{
    ...
    Usuario usuar;

    ...
    public Usuario Usuar
    {
        get { return usuar; }
        set { usuar = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont get any error but all the items on my dropdown are like empty strings .

Comment: the property name belongs to the superclass could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers I solved adding this code to the Profesional

```
        public String Nombre
    {
        get { return usuar.Nombre; }
        set { usuar.Nombre = value; }
    }
```